# How does one deal with missing data of unbalanced longitudinal data? And what about multivariate case?

Tags: regression, bayesian, panel-data, multiple-imputation

For balanced longitudinal data, the missing data can be handled by multiple imputation in wide format where I assume MAR.

However, for unbalanced longitudinal data(i.e. number of measurements varying from subject to subject), I cannot cast the data in wide format to do multiple imputation, if there is missing entries.

Q1: How does one do multiple imputation in unbalanced case? Or is multiple imputation preferred anymore? Should full Bayesian model be considered here? If so, what should one do for sensitivity analysis(prior, model itself)?

Q2: Since multiple imputation is concerned about a single outcome, how do I deal with multivariate outcome case in unbalanced setting?